# Nexus S3 blobstore doesn't work with S3 interface endpoint in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nexus, nexus3, vpc-endpoint

I have an EC2 instance in one private subnet. And I have an S3 interface endpoint in another private subnet. Both are in same VPC.

In my NACL rules, I have below

```
Outbound 0.0.0.0 All-traffic
Inbound VPC-CIDR All-traffic
```

Nexus is running in the EC2 instance. In Nexus blobstore configuration I enabled "Endpoint URL" option and provided the S3 interface endpoint URL.

```
https://bucket.vpce***.s3.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com
```

But once after I enabled "Endpoint URL" option, I am not able to upload artifact into Nexus and getting Gateway timeout error.

When I do from the EC2 instance,

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce***.s3.us-east-2.vpce.amazonaws.com
```

it works fine. And also "aws s3 cp" works fine as well.

But Nexus blobstore is not able to upload the object to S3.

If I add below rule in NACL,

```
Inbound 0.0.0.0 All-traffic
```

Nexus works fine.

Comment: Also try asking this question on https://community.sonatype.com/, where it's much more likely to get a answer.